# Android - ViewPager won't let me change page when clicking on listview item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Trying to make news feed app in android which takes json from url and parses it into listview with costum adapter. My goal is to switch the page to the third fragment with the "browser view" which displays the new from given url. **The problem is that when the user clicks on any item from the listview, the viewpager won't change it's page.**

I have three seperate layouts for each fragment and one "main" fragment with the viewpager in it. The onclick-event is attached to the listview:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View mainview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) mainview.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setAdapter(new costumAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.list_row, refresh()));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("Clicked item: ", String.valueOf(position));  //works
            model m = (model) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            System.out.println( m.url); //works

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, true); //Doesnt work...
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

The refresh() method returns the json data so we can put it inside the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem like this without inflater:

```
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true);
```